# Multi product sales forecasting

Tags: python

I have a dataframe as such

```
Keys Date          x1       x2           x3    ..... x112          Sales

665  1-Jun-2012   58766.56  0          44111        28512.43     285900
.
.
.
665 1-Jan-2018   43455.21  26511.22    26544       221444.32     31875


711  1-Jun-2012   6343.12  123411.45  422211       79153.11      216754
.
.
.
711 1-Jan-2018    11454.33 2214.28    313922       665471        190445
```

The keys are the products and x1-x112 are the set of predictors for the sales(target). The data runs from Jan 2012 to June 2018. I would like to forecast sales for the period Jun 2018 to Jan 2019 for each product for a given month. I have a test set for this.

I have done some feature engineering by running a correlation of the features with the target and also correlation within features and got 9 features. These are x3,x8,x11,x13,x17,x18,x26,x39,x43 respectively.[I have added an image to show the distribution of sales using an ms resample method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scnEW.png)

There are total of 119 products.

how do I tackle this problem? I understand that this is a multivariate time series.